# Angular validation in nested directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Hello I wanna use angular directive for every input in my app. I ve made some simple directive with many attributes, but I dont know how to make validation. Validation requires unique 'name' parameter but I am using many input in one form, so I am trying to pass it:

```
<form name="form" ng-controller="sampleController" novalidate>
    <div data-input-row data="form.father.name" name="fatherName" placeholder="placeholder" label="father name"></div>
    <div data-input-row data="form.father.surname" name="fatherSurname" placeholder="placeholder" label="father surname"></div>
    <div data-input-row data="form.mother.name" name="motherName" placeholder="placeholder" label="mother name"></div>
    <div data-input-row data="form.mother.surname" name="motherSurname" placeholder="placeholder" label="mother surname"></div>
</form>
```

directive:

```
   restrict: 'A',
   scope: {
      data: '=',
      name: '@',
      required: '@',
      type: '@',
      placeholder: '@',
      label: '@',
      rendered: '@'
   },
   link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      //1: maybe someone knows better way for default parameters values than this ifs ?
      if (!attrs.type) { attrs.type = 'text'; }
      if (!attrs.rendered) { attrs.rendered = 'true'; }
      if (!attrs.required) { attrs.required = 'false'; }
    },
    templateUrl: UrlConfig.BasicUrlConfig.APPLICATION_URL + '/app/modules/directives/input/inputRow.html'
```

html:

```
<div ng-if="rendered == 'true'" class="input-control">
   <label for="input">{{label}}</label>
   //2: maybe someone knows better way for optional required param than copy of input ?
   <input id="input" ng-if="required != 'true'" type="{{type}}" name="{{name}}" ng-model="data" placeholder="{{placeholder}}" />
   <input id="input" ng-if="required == 'true'" type="{{type}}" name="{{name}}" ng-model="data" placeholder="{{placeholder}}" required/>

    //3: name should be unique so it should be parametrized, but how to type it then: ng-show="form.{{name}}.$invalid" ?????
    //this section is never showing up.
    <span class="error" ng-show="form.{{name}}.$invalid && form.{{name}}.$dirty">
      {{label}} required!
    </span>
    <span class="error" ng-show="form.{{name}}.$error.number">
      {{label}} not valid number!
    </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should use `ng-required` and you use `[]` for dynamic object name. Try this:

```
<div ng-if="rendered == 'true'" class="input-control">
    <label for="input">{{label}}</label>
    //2: ng-required is a saviour
    <input id="input" ng-required="required == 'true'" type="{{type}}" name="{{name}}" ng-model="data" placeholder="{{placeholder}}" />

    //3: Use [ variable_name ] for dynamic object name like object[ variable_name ]
    <span class="error" ng-show="form[name].$invalid && form[name].$dirty">
      {{label}} required!
    </span>
    <span class="error" ng-show="form[name].$error.number">
      {{label}} not valid number!
    </span>
</div>
```

I am still not sure whether it will work because you `form` is out of scope. I think you will have to pass form variable through directive too.

Comment: 2. I dont know why but with ng-required = false  inputs gets also ng-valid-required class. Iam using this class for highlight required fields.
3. it not works I am trying with passing form, but it doesnt work also, how to pass form instead of string 'form'?

Comment: use it in combination with `.ng-pristine`, like `.ng-valid-required:not( .ng-pristine )`. `.ng-pristine` class means that user never entered any value there in which case you won't highlight it